# Condition operator, doesn't react on condition changes, I guess

Tags: javascript, reactjs, default-value, conditional-operator

I have a React component representing a form with inputs (Text, Number, Date). The date input has a default value - `today`. I use this component for two functions: creating an object and editing an object. In the first case, all inputs are empty by default, except for the date input, which is set to `today`. In the second case, the inputs receive default values from optional props (`values`) that are passed to the component from the parent component's state. The component is rendered on the page in two instances, one with `values` passed and one without. Since the presence of `values` is optional, I included a conditional operator in the default values of each input. In the case of the date input, it looks like this:

`defaultValue={inputValues?.date ? inputValues.date : today}`

In other cases, an empty string `''` is used instead of `today`.

I expected that when the state changes, the component would re-render and insert the `values` into the default inputs. In practice, this only happens with inputs that are initially empty, while the date input always has the value `today`.

Through the console, I see that when the component is rendered, `inputValue` = undefined (useState is set with empty brackets, so it's not a surprise), so initially I assumed that the `values` do not appear by the time of rendering. However, when the edit button is clicked, the correct `values` are displayed in the console. In my understanding, at this point, the component should re-render and insert the `values` according to the expression `{inputValues?.date ? inputValues.date : today}`. However, in fact, the value of the date picker is `today`, and the value of all other inputs is `values`. If you replace today with an `''` in the expression, then when the edit function is called, the value of the date picker in the edit form is `inputValues.date`, but the default value in the creation form is now empty, because `today` is not set in this case.

This behavior is not exclusive to the date picker; any other input behaves in the same way if you replace `''` with any value in the expression. I would be very glad if you could explain this behavior and how to fix it.

Here is a test example:"

```
function App() {
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState();
    const change = () => setValues({ name: 'name', date: '2023-11-28' });
    return (
        <Child values={values} change={change} />
    );
}

function Child({ values, change }) {
    console.log(values);
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <button type="button" onClick={change} >clickMe</button>
            <input type="text" defaultValue={values?.name ? values.name : ''} />
            <input type="date" defaultValue={values?.date ? values.date : '2023-11-20'} />
        </div>
    );
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: `defaultValue` should not be abled to be changed after the first render iirc. I think you'll need to use `value` instead

Comment: Well, value is not an option, cause it won't allow user to change value, I could use onChange or something, but it's more academic question at this point. 
I kinda understand that `defaultValue` suppose to be static. What I don't understand, how can it be saved, if compnent suppose to re-render at state change. And if it is re-renders, then html doesn't suppose to know that `defaultValue` was `prevValue`, it should take value that come from the expression, which is re-calculates at the re-render. 
Am I wrong?

And if it's cannot be changed, why does it changes from `''` to `value'?

Comment: React only re-render what it considers as "need to be updated". As far as I know, React won't keep track on `defaultValue` (and it makes sense!) so even when you set defaultValue to something else, React will just ignore it.

But tbh I'm not that acquainted with how React actually work under the hood, so take my words as a grain of sand.

Also, I'm not sure why you want to refrain from `onChange` when it's the official recommendation for controlled input.

Comment: I know that React update 'when it's needed', though I thought it's gonna be 'needed' simply because state has changed, without considering how it's used.
I wasn't try to specificly avoid `onChange`, it's just looked simplier this way.

Comment: when you dont have `value` of an input connected to a state value (directly or via props) the input behaves as a uncontrolled input. So your inputs will have `value={undefined}` at all times from react's pov. You need to connect it to the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is related to the fact that the defaultValue attribute is only set once when the component initially renders. Changing the values prop doesn't trigger a re-render of the child component, so the defaultValue remains unchanged.

```
function Child({ values, change }) {
  return (
      <div className="container">
          <button type="button" onClick={change} >clickMe</button>
          <input type="text" value={values?.name ? values.name : ''} />
          <input type="date" value={values?.date ? values.date : '2023-11-20'} />
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In that case, why does it work with the `name` and doesn't with the `date`? Because `''` doesn't count as a value? So the problem is that component doesn't re-render at all? It just sets the values where there wasn't?
If so, force-re-render should solve everything.

Comment: The issue with the date input arises from the way browsers handle the defaultValue attribute for the `<input type="date" />`. When the defaultValue of a date input is set to an empty string (''), browsers tend to default to displaying the current date.

Comment: In your case, when you set defaultValue={values?.date ? values.date : ''}, it doesn't have the intended effect of making the date input blank when values.date is not provided. Instead, the browser interprets an empty string as a request to use the current date as the default.

Comment: You also may have warning message on the console and rerenders twice. 
To avoid warnings about changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled, and to ensure that the component re-renders correctly, you should use the `useState` hook to manage the state of the `name` and `date` values inside the `Child` component.

Comment: That's not exectly correct. If I leave `defaultValue` of a date input with an empty string, then it's value is 'empty' - it appears as 'dd-mm-yyyy'. I just checked it.
And it doesn't expain why `name` value does change. It really looks like browser don't count `''` as a value, `defaultValue` doesn't exist at this time. So when I change `name`, from the browser prespective, I don't change it but set it.

Comment: When you use an empty string as the defaultValue for a text input, it correctly renders an empty input field. In contrast, the date input interprets an empty string as a request for the default date format.
To handle this, and to ensure consistent behavior for both text and date inputs, you can use undefined instead of an empty string for the defaultValue:

`<input type="date" defaultValue={values?.date ? values.date : undefined} />`

Comment: I would take note for using undefined instead of an empty string, but in this case I need an alternative variant for `defaultValue` to be a today's date, not an undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default values for every prop that is given to the component. I've altered the structure of your code a bit, making it more readable and easier to use.

```js
// App.js
import Child from "./Child";

const App = () => {
  const onSubmitChild = (values) => {
    console.log(values);

    // Lazy way of dumping variable value into element lol
    document.getElementById("vardump").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(values);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Child
        onSubmit={onSubmitChild}
        defaultValues={{ name: "name", date: "2020-12-31" }}
      />
      <br />
      <code id="vardump" />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;

// Child.js
import { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Child = ({ onSubmit, defaultValues }) => {
  // This state contains the value for all inputs, two in this case
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: defaultValues.name,
    date: defaultValues.date,
  });

  const handleChangeName = (e) => {
    const element = e.currentTarget;

    // This will only edit the state for "name"
    setValues({
      ...values,
      name: element.value,
    });
  };

  const handleChangeDate = (e) => {
    const element = e.currentTarget;

    // This will only edit the state for "date"
    setValues({
      ...values,
      date: element.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button type="submit" onClick={() => onSubmit(values)}>
        clickMe
      </button>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        defaultValue={defaultValues.name}
        value={values.name}
        onChange={handleChangeName}
      />
      <input
        type="date"
        name="date"
        defaultValue={defaultValues.date}
        value={values.date}
        onChange={handleChangeDate}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

Child.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  defaultValues: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default Child;
```

This way, the inputs change the value on their own, allowing the user to edit the contents of the input. And when the user clicks the "clickMe" submit button, the component `App` will get these values and allows you for further implementation. For now, I've made it so that `<App />` just dumps the value into `<code id="vardump" />`, so you will be able to see the difference easily.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactjs-answer-xtqfc3